# Setting axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pycharm

I'm learning matplotlib from [guide](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html) and I'm having troubles with *moving spines*.
 After setting x and y axis

```
pl.xticks([-np.pi, -np.pi/2, 0, np.pi/2, np.pi],
      [r'$-\pi$', r'$-\pi/2$', r'$0$', r'$+\pi/2$', r'$+\pi$'])
pl.yticks([-1, 0, +1],
      [r'$-1$', r'$0$', r'$+1$'])
```

They are using `spines` function:

```
ax = pl.gca()
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data',0))
```

To move axis towards the middle. After I did that, my previously defined axis are lost and my plot looks like [this](http://i59.tinypic.com/nnwbd2.jpg)
How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do those two things in other order, see [the source code for the picture](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/matplotlib/auto_examples/plot_exercice_7.html) for an example.